# Open and Change Windows Settings via Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Please let me know if this would be better asked in SuperUsers.

I know you can open Settings in powershell via:

```
Start-Process ms-settings:
```

But I want to open up in a specific location in settings (in this case, "Devices -> Pen & Windows Ink")

```
Start-Process "ms-settings:Devices\Pen & Windows Ink"
```

Okay, apparently that works :P  I was just typing that as pseudo-code, but apparently it works.  So never mind about that first part of the question.

[**EDIT** Yesterday, the above code worked, but now it doesn't.  Since yesterday, I have made changes in the `$profile` document, but I can't see how what I did could have made this no longer work]

How would I toggle the "Ignore touch input when I'm using my pen" setting, such as this pseudo-code that better not work (or else that would just be scary)

```
Toggle-Setting "ms-settings:Device\Pen & Windows Ink\Ignore touch when I'm using my pen"
```

(Okay good, it doesn't work this time)

If you need to do something in the registry, please explain how to avoid messing up something important.

Comment: "I'd prefer not to change anything in that [the registry] if it's possible" - that's exactly what many (if not most?) of the settings changes do (change something in the registry).

Comment: Alright, I thought so.  In that case I would appreciate any guidance about how to make sure I don't totally mess up anything, because every time something online tells me to change the registry, ti advises to backup the whole thing just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the registry is your best option here. 
Other then that, you might be able by sending message to the windows once open but that would be the long (and breakable) way around.

To do the specific you want, use the following:

```
$registryPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Pen"
$GetValue = {Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $registryPath -Name 'PenArbitrationType'}

Write-Host "Initial value is $($GetValue.Invoke())" -ForegroundColor Cyan
# on
Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name 'PenArbitrationType' -Value 1
Write-Host "Item property is now set to: $($GetValue.Invoke()) "
# off 
Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name 'PenArbitrationType' -Value 3
Write-Host "Item property is now set to: $($GetValue.Invoke()) "
```

You can see this in action if you open **regedit**, go to the path above, then use the UI to change the value manually. If you refresh your regedit, you will see that the value alternate between 1 (on) and 3 (off).

That's basically all the UI do for you when you toggle that setting.

**Reference:** 
[Turn On or Off Ignore Touch Input when using Pen in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/111017-turn-off-ignore-touch-input-when-using-pen-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: When I set it on, typing `Get-ItemProperty` for that attribute says that it's on, but nothing changes when I test it with my pen or in settings.  When I change the option in Settings, `Get-ItemProperty` will give the correct value, but when I change the option in PowerShell, only `Get-ItemProperty` changes and not checkbox in Settings (even after restarting the app), and testing with the pen also reveals that it's still on or off (whatever it was set to in Settings).

Comment: @ElliotThomas I think you need to **sign-out** after changing the setting and **sign-in** again for it to take effect

Comment: @Theo what do I need to sign-out of?  And how do I do that?

Comment: @ElliotThomas ehhhhhhhhhhhhhh.. like [this](https://logoffwindows.com/)

Comment: @Theo lol, I thought that was it, but I wasn't sure if you were talking about something else or not.  Is there a way to do this without having to sign in and out?

Comment: @ElliotThomas Maybe stopping and starting the `explorer` process forces to re-read the registry, but I'm not sure. You could try coding a `SendMessageTimeout` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207513/immediately-apply-registry-changes), but chances are that's not going to work.

Comment: @ElliotThomas Can you confirm you are indeed using Windows 10 ?

Comment: @SagePourpre I am using Windows 10.

Comment: @ElliotThomas Is your setting windows open when you do it through Powershell ? If so, try using Powershell but without having the setting windows open at the same time. I unfortunately does not have that option in my setting to test further myself, which is probably due to my lack of pen.

Comment: Bascially, Make sure your setting is off and that the configuration window or setting window is not open. Run the script to turn it on. Test if it works. My thought is that these new settings window Autosave change without "Apply" button. Therefore, if you tested the change while having the setting window open in parallel, the settings app might have overwrited the registry value on close rather than reading from registry at that point.

Comment: @SagePourpre I've tested it both with Settings opened and closed, and it didn't work both times.